# How to return a texture from pixel shader in Unity 3d shaderlab?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader, pixel-shader

How to create a simple pixel color shader that say takes a texture, applyes something like masking:

```
half4 color = tex2D(_Texture0, i.uv.xy);
if(distance(color, mask) > _CutOff)
{
    return color;
}
else
{
return static_color;
}
```

in and returns a texture that can be passed to next shader from c# code in a way like `mats[1].SetTexture("_MainTex", mats[0].GetTexture("_MainTex"));`?

Comment: Have you tried the Unity help forum? That's quite a specific question you got there. But... you might not want to do a shader to only modify a texture.

Answer (score 4):

> But... you might not want to do a shader to only modify a texture.

Why not? It is a common practice.

Check out **Graphics.Blit**. It basically draws a quad with material (including a shader) applied. So you could use your shader to modify a texture. But the texture has to be RenderTexture.

It would be like this:

```
var mat = new Material(Shader.Find("My Shader"));
var output = new RenderTexture(...);
Graphics.Blit(sourceTexture, output, mat);
```

sourceTexture in this case will be bound to _MainTex of **My Shader**.

Comment: How do you get the pixel data back out of the RenderTexture?

Comment: You do this with http://docs.unity3d.ru/ScriptReference/Texture2D.ReadPixels.html.

Comment: you may well be able to easily answer this, @ValentinSimonov cheers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34952184/pixel-perfect-shader-in-unity